# Mysql 5.1 spatial overlaps why doesn't work properly?

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I'm doing some test with spatial operations on MySQL 5.1 and I've found some problems overlaping a mutlipolygon with a polygon.
Test set
1) Multipolygon: Are 2 polygons on it, one represents continental France and other one Corsica
2) Polygon. Just a rectangle.
3) Multipolygon and polygon, doesn't overlap. Testesd with JTS test builder
4) MySQL returns that overlaps.

I'm doing something wrong? Do you know wether overlaping it considers the multipolygon bounding box instead of the multipolygon borders (looks like it is this case).

Thanks in advance,

Xavi

Here the test query:

```
SELECT   overlaps(
GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(
((
-1.5719044 45.66331767,
-1.66445017 44.15596196,
-2.09633041 43.35382557,
-1.44851005 42.79046377,
0.98852813 42.40442147,
2.16077434 42.15335565,
3.57980926 42.24476801,
3.36386913 42.9035504,
4.13508385 43.24156757,
6.44872768 42.69984551,
8.00528012 44.22125179,
7.43172878 44.63085344,
7.47952458 45.30714395,
6.9537692 46.70140581,
8.10087187 47.70798437,
8.19646379 48.47416978,
8.67442321 49.16649286,
5.42429902 49.94163752,
4.75515576 50.46172136,
2.07858291 51.36572924,
1.1226639 50.82543226,
0.59690852 50.21768192,
-0.69358204 49.6640024,
-1.98407259 50.06452024,
-2.55762393 49.5090723,
-1.93627663 48.9472454,
-2.55762393 48.88442555,
-3.99150219 49.16649286,
-5.37758466 48.60075831,
-5.42538062 47.90060118,
-4.03929815 47.41771923,
-2.84439951 46.96299696,
-2.03186838 46.2405562,
-1.5719044 45.66331767,
-1.5719044 45.66331767
)),
((
7.03485087 43.06152362,
8.23794566 42.56366976,
8.19646379 41.73912551,
8.67442321 41.09395768,
9.86932185 41.20193051,
9.86932185 42.72995934,
9.1523828 43.49754453,
8.23794566 42.56366976,
7.03485087 43.06152362,
7.03485087 43.06152362
))
)
')
, 

GeomFromText('POLYGON((
1.1578032214844 40.974486726133,
1.1578032214844 41.79873497231,
3.1820341785157  41.79873497231,
3.1820341785157 40.974486726133,
1.1578032214844 40.974486726133
))')
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlaps and MBROverlaps are the same function on MysQL 5.1. I missed this comment on the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html) :

***Note**
Currently, MySQL does not implement these functions according to the specification. Those that are implemented return the same result as the corresponding MBR-based functions.*

Seems that from MySQL 5.6 onwards mysql will support Overlaps on polygons, [ST_Overlaps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_st-overlaps).